# Storing numbers from a file into a 2-D array

Tags: java

This code will read in double values from a file and store them in a 2-D array. I'm practicing using only arrays (not ArrayLists). The maximum number of lines that will be stored is 10, 10 values max per line. Values in the file are separated by a single white space character. Any feedback would be appreciated as well as any suggestions to make this more efficient.

````
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class twoDArrayPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            Scanner inputFile;
            inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            final int ROWS = 10;
            final int COLS = 10;
            String[][] numString = new String[ROWS][COLS]; // 2-d array of strings
            StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0, j = 0;

            // stores contents from file into numString
            while (inputFile.hasNextLine() && i < 10) {
                tempString.append(inputFile.nextLine());
                if (!(tempString.toString().trim().isEmpty())) {
                    numString[i] = removeSpaces(tempString.toString().split(" "));
                    i++;
                }
                tempString.setLength(0);
            }

            inputFile.close();
            i = 0;

            // counts and stores number of non-null rows from numString 
            //in i variable
            while (i != 10 && numString[i][0] != null) {
                i++;
            }


            Double[][] doubleMatrix = new Double[i][];
            int doubleMatrixLength = doubleMatrix.length, numStringLength = 0;

            //takes elements in numString, parses them to 
            //double and stores them in doubleMatrix
            for (i = 0; i < doubleMatrixLength; i++) {
                numStringLength = numString[i].length;
                for (j = 0; j < numStringLength; j++) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        doubleMatrix[i] = new Double[numString[i].length];
                    }
                    try {
                        doubleMatrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numString[i][j]);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't convert to double");
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        System.out.println("Can't convert Null value");
                    }
                }
            }

            //print contents of doubleMatrix
            for (i = 0; i < doubleMatrix.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < doubleMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(doubleMatrix[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }

    //returns new array with spaces removed from stringArray
    public static String[] removeSpaces(String[] stringArray) {
        String[] newArray;
        int newLength = 0, oldLength = stringArray.length;

        //counts number of non-empty elements in string array
        for (int i = 0; i < oldLength; i++) {
            if (!(isBlankString(stringArray[i]))) {
                newLength++;
            }
        }

        newArray = new String[newLength];
        int j = 0;

        //copies over elements from stringArray to newArray
        for (int i = 0; i < oldLength; i++) {
            if (!(isBlankString(stringArray[i]))) {
                newArray[j] = stringArray[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

        return newArray;
    }

    //checks if str is blank as well as if its a double
    public static boolean isBlankString(String str) {
        return str == null || str.isEmpty() || !isDouble(str);
    }

    public static boolean isDouble(String str) {
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Code Review. I have some suggestions for you and I modified part of your code in your `main` , using just only arrays as you said:

Starting from your class declaration:

> ```
> public class twoDArrayPractice { ... }
> ```

Java classes always start with an uppercase letter, you can rename it:

```
public class TwoDArrayPractice { ... }
```

Use of [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, why worry about closing of one file if there is a construct automatically doing it for you ? So instead of :

> ```
> try {
>       File file = new File("test.txt");
>       Scanner inputFile;
>       inputFile = new Scanner(file);
>       inputFile.close();
> } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>         System.out.println("File not found");
> }
> ```

You can rewrite it like this:

```
try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) { /* here your code */ }
```

Some minor changes to your `main` method  to improve readibility:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final int ROWS = 10;
    final int COLS = 10;
    String[][] numString = new String[ROWS][COLS]; // 2-d array of strings

    try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) { /* here your code */ }
}
```

You have the following code:

> ```
> while (inputFile.hasNextLine() && i < 10) {
>        tempString.append(inputFile.nextLine());
>        if (!(tempString.toString().trim().isEmpty())) {
>            numString[i] = removeSpaces(tempString.toString().split(" "));
>            i++;
>        }
>        tempString.setLength(0);
> }
> ```

Rewrite it in a more readable way:

```
for (int i = 0; inputFile.hasNextLine() && i < 10; ++i) {
    String line = inputFile.nextLine();
    if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        numString[i] = removeSpaces(line.split(" "));
    }
}
```

Same approach for this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < doubleMatrixLength; i++) {
    numStringLength = numString[i].length;
    for (j = 0; j < numStringLength; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
       doubleMatrix[i] = new Double[numString[i].length];
    }
    try {
       doubleMatrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numString[i][j]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't convert to double");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      System.out.println("Can't convert Null value");
    }
}
```

You can rewrite like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < doubleMatrix.length; i++) {
    int numStringLength = numString[i].length;
    doubleMatrix[i] = new Double[numStringLength];
    for (int j = 0; j < numStringLength; j++) {
    try {
        doubleMatrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numString[i][j]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't convert to double");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't convert Null value");
    }
}
```

Here the complete version of method `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final int ROWS = 10;
    final int COLS = 10;
    String[][] numString = new String[ROWS][COLS]; // 2-d array of strings

    try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {

        // stores contents from file into numString
        for (int i = 0; inputFile.hasNextLine() && i < 10; ++i) {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                numString[i] = removeSpaces(line.split(" "));
            }
        }

        // counts and stores number of non-null rows from numString 
        //in n variable
        int n = 0;
        while (n != 10 && numString[n][0] != null) { n++; }


        Double[][] doubleMatrix = new Double[n][];

        //takes elements in numString, parses them to 
        //double and stores them in doubleMatrix
        for (int i = 0; i < doubleMatrix.length; i++) {
            int numStringLength = numString[i].length;
            doubleMatrix[i] = new Double[numStringLength];
            for (int j = 0; j < numStringLength; j++) {
                try {
                    doubleMatrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numString[i][j]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't convert to double");
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    System.out.println("Can't convert Null value");
                }
            }
        }

        //print contents of doubleMatrix
        for (n = 0; n < doubleMatrix.length; n++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < doubleMatrix[n].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(doubleMatrix[n][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

With `List` and generally dynamic structures the code would be extremely simpler.